# making update API dynamic

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, api, sequelize.js

small question, how can I make this API takes only the define json key from my request, without checking every single key in my request using `if statement` like below  :

```
const updateArticle = async (req, res) => {
  const { title, description, body } = req.body;
  try {
    const article = await Article.findByPk(req.params.id);

    if (title) article.title = title;
    if (description) article.description = description;
    if (body) article.body = body;

    await article.save();

    res.json("Article updated.");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Object.assign()` method to override the properties of your *source* object to your *target* object.

```js
const updateArticle = async (req, res) => {
  const { title, description, body } = req.body;
  try {
    const article = await Article.findByPk(req.params.id);

    Object.assign(article, req.body);

    await article.save();

    res.json("Article updated.");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```